# In Oracle DB, can Indexes span acrosss more than one datafile like tables can?

Tags: oracle

While reading the official docs, I'm trying to understand exactly what objects in the db are segmented between data files or data spaces and what aren't.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm

Thanks to all who chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Logical objects, such as indexes and tables, can be stored across many physical objects, such as data files.

Tables and indexes are usually assigned to a single tablespace each, although if they are partitioned each partition can use a different tablespace.